# How to use Artifactory plugin in Jenkins to add recursive properties to existing artifact in Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I already know how to add properties to the folder recursively with Arty REST api 
curl -X PUT http://myserver:8081/artifactory/api/storage/myrepo/myfolder?properties=testing=something&recursive=1

And I found these examples of Artifactory plugin usage in Jenkins

```
rtMaven.deployer.addProperty("status", "in-qa")
rtGradle.deployer.addProperty("status", "in-qa")
rtDocker.addProperty("project-name", "docker1")
```

There are features for maven, gradle and docker
Can do the same thing but with any folder in artifactory?

Comment: Documentation is here: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins. Check there to see.

Comment: This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but JFrog CLI includes a set-props command which accepts file specs. It supports recursive in addition to advanced filtering options.